# how to query data from multiple tables and display one record specific to each device relative to their last working date

Tags: mysql

Hi I am new to mysql database can any one help to my problem
I have three tables like this

```
select * from device;
Vehiclegroup  vehicleName  deviceid  accountid  
------------  -----------  --------  -----------
sms           cargo        test1      sysadmin   
sms           cargo1       test2     sysadmin   
sms           cargo3       test3     sysadmin   
select * from Account;
accountid  password  deviceid  
---------  --------  ----------
sysadmin   pass      test3     
sysadmin   pass      test2     
sysadmin   pass      test1     
And finally 

mysql> select * from eventdata;
+-----------+-------+----------+----------+
| accountid | speed | date     | deviceid |
+-----------+-------+----------+----------+
| sysadmin  | 45    | 12/10/13 | test3    |
| sysadmin  | 45    | 10/10/13 | test3    |
| sysadmin  | 45    | 10/10/13 | test2    |
| sysadmin  | 45    | 11/10/13 | test2    |
| sysadmin  | 45    | 14/10/13 | test2    |
| sysadmin  | 45    | 17/10/13 | test2    |
| sysadmin  | 45    | 17/10/13 | test1    |
+-----------+-------+----------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

here i need output table as shown below

```
vehiclegroup vehiclename deviceid date
sms              cargo1  test1  17/10/13
sms              cargo2  test2  17/10/13
sms              cargo3  test3  12/10/13
```

i.e i need data for each device for the last working date 
can any one help for this

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT d.Vehiclegroup, d.vehicleName, e.deviceid, e.date
FROM eventdata e
INNER JOIN device d ON e.deviceid = d.deviceid
GROUP BY e.deviceid
```

Will give you one record per deviceid. 
The Vehiclegroup, vehiclename and date are chosen arbitrary from the list.
If you want the latest, you should use a subquery or modifier, like ( MAX(e.date) as date)

Comment: Thank @Tom for giving reply.ur query displays every record but i don't want every record i.e it display for test(4 records0 and for test3(2 records) but i need to display only one record for test2(17/10/13) and for test3(12/10/13) records only

Comment: can u post example for it